# why is a _partial in sass included

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, materialize

I have a partial sass called "_color.scss" where it has these code from materializecss.

```
$materialize-red: (
 "base":       #e51c23,
  "lighten-5":  #fdeaeb,
  "lighten-4":  #f8c1c3,
  "lighten-3":  #f3989b,
  "lighten-2":  #ee6e73,
  "lighten-1":  #ea454b,
  "darken-1":   #d0181e,
  "darken-2":   #b9151b,
  "darken-3":   #a21318,
  "darken-4":   #8b1014,
);
...

@each $color_name, $color in $colors {
  @each $color_type, $color_value in $color {
    @if $color_type == "base" {
      .#{$color_name} {
        background-color: $color_value !important;
      }
      .#{$color_name}-text {
        color: $color_value !important;
      }
    }
    @else if $color_name != "shades" {
      .#{$color_name}.#{$color_type} {
        background-color: $color_value !important;
      }
      .#{$color_name}-text.text-#{$color_type} {
        color: $color_value !important;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Shade classes
@each $color, $color_value in $shades {
  .#{$color} {
    background-color: $color_value !important;
  }
  .#{$color}-text {
    color: $color_value !important;
  }
}


// usage: color("name_of_color", "type_of_color")
// to avoid to repeating map-get($colors, ...)

@function color($color, $type) {
  @if map-has-key($colors, $color) {
    $curr_color: map-get($colors, $color);
    @if map-has-key($curr_color, $type) {
      @return map-get($curr_color, $type);
    }
  }
  @warn "Unknown `#{name}` in $colors.";
  @return null;
}
```

Then in my every other .scss files, i import that in.

```
@import "../../bower_components/materialize/sass/components/color";
```

Given this statement by their site, "The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and that it should not be generated into a CSS file.", should this be excluded from the actual css? But my current environment is including the partial into my css

was it something to do with my grunt?

Comment: follow this doc https://sass-lang.com/ruby-sass

Comment: Can you post your gruntfile so we can see that too?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to include the partial file in every over sass file, it defeats the purpose. 
What does your file structure look like? 
For example, my file structure would look something like:

```
main.scss
_variables.scss
_mixins.scss
_grid.scss
_whatever.scss
```

and then within main.scss

```
@import 'variables'
@import 'mixins'
@import 'grid'
@import 'whatever'
```

With grunt or sass you are then compiling main.scss , or using sass:

```
sass --watch main.scss:style.css
```

Comment: i have

main.scss
component1.scss
component2.scss


in these components.scss, there are some variables i might want to use in the _colour.scss. But from materializecss, both declaration of variables are then output into the css as like what the foreach function is for

Answer (score 0):

Without the underscore, there is a chance that your build tool (grunt) will output a CSS file for every SCSS file in your folders. For example, with this folder structure (without underscores):

```
my_project
    scss
        main.scss
        colors.scss
        mixins.scss
        component1.scss
        component2.scss
```

grunt might output a CSS file for every partial:

```
my_project
    css
        main.css
        colors.css
        mixins.css
        component1.css
        component2.css
```

Most people don't want this, so we use underscores to tell grunt not to compile every file, like so:

```
my_project
    scss
        main.scss
        _colors.scss
        _mixins.scss
        _component1.scss
        _component2.scss
```

This will output as:

```
my_project
    css
        main.css
```